# Update statement failing without any rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

On a SQL Server 2005 database a stored procedure that had been working starting failing. The following statement in the stored procedure was determined to be the cause of the failure:

```
update d set
d.location=a.[Name]+'-'+cast(a.lLocaId as varchar)
--select d.logical_name,d.location,a.[Name]+'-'+cast(a.lLocaId as varchar) as location
from hpsmp.dbo.device2m1 d
inner join hpsmp.dbo.locm1 s
on d.location=s.location
inner join hpamp.dbo.amLocation a
on s.location_code=a.lLocaId
where isnumeric(s.location_code)=1
and s.location_name<>a.[Name];
```

The error message is

Msg 8152, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.

What is odd about this error is that the select statement is not returning any rows. Why would there be a truncation error in an update statement without any rows? There are no triggers on this table.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but worth noting : did you ever try running `SELECT IsNumeric('1e6')` ?

Comment: Are you sure you're `select` statement doesn't return any results?   This fiddle works (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8f26d1/1), but if you remove the `where` criteria, it results in the truncation error.

Comment: `select IsNumeric('1e6')` returns 1

Answer (score 2):

Your question is really:  "*What is odd about this error is that the select statement is not returning any rows. Why would there be a truncation error in an update statement without any rows?* "

First, when you do the conversion to `varchar` you should *always* include a length:

```
set d.location = a.[Name] + '-' + cast(a.lLocaId as varchar(255))
```

SQL Server has different default lengths in different contexts, so this could cause a problem.  Not the one you are seeing but another one.

I believe that what is happening is that SQL Server constructs the execution plan for the query and it moves the calculation of the new value of `location` *before* the filtering.  In other words, it can do the calculation while reading `hpamp.dbo.amLocation` because that is the only table needed for the new value.

Then, it gets an error even on a row that is not being updated.

This is a bit of speculation, but SQL Server does exhibit this behavior in other places.  A notorious problem is getting an error when you do:

```
select cast(col as datetime)
from table t
where isdate(col) = 1;
```

Yes, this also produces errors on invalid dates and for the same reason.

In your case, I'm not sure what the best way to fix the problem is.  You could try something like:

```
set d.location = (case when len(a.name) < 8 then a.[Name] + '-' + cast(a.lLocaId as varchar(255)) end)
```

I made up the number `8`, but if you set an appropriate value, then it should work.

Comment: Adding a cast using the length of the destination column resolved this problem. `d.location=cast(a.[Name]+'-'+cast(a.lLocaId as varchar) as varchar(60))`